# ssr vue vue server side rendering webpack example: what happened to main template/layout file?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, server-side-rendering

In the ssr vue (server side rendering for vuejs) documentation there's a code structure example containing a webpack build step:

https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/structure.html

The structure looks like this:

```
src
├── components
│   ├── Foo.vue
│   ├── Bar.vue
│   └── Baz.vue
├── App.vue
├── app.js # universal entry
├── entry-client.js # runs in browser only
└── entry-server.js # runs on server only
```

I am missing a main template(in rails or expressjs lingo a layout) which is supposed to contain the

```
<!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
```

marker.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In SSR there is not a layouts folder. Your template (default) is in your App.vue file.